# laravel file manager doesn't show uploaded images

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with laravel file manager and i couldn't find anyway to solve it.

My project has developed via laravel 5. I use CKEditor for publishing articles in my site. I added laravel file manager to CKEditor to make it possible to upload image in my article. It was ok and there was no error for 2 months, but from one week ago I have this problem. The problem is:
The images are uploading correctly. I see them in the corresponding folders.

But nothing shows up in the file manager. When uploading a picture the page doesn't refresh and keep saying it's uploading.

Also when I open any folder in laravel file manager it returns 500 internal server error.

There are others that have the same problem.

Maybe this link is useful:
https://github.com/tsawler/laravel-filemanager

Comment: The "500 Internal Server Error" means there's something going wrong with a script on the server. Check the server logs to see what the error is.

Comment: the error log is empty

Comment: I don't think so. Are you running Apache? What OS/distribution? Do you have VirtualHosts? What is php.ini's `error_log` setting? On Debian with Apache and a VirtualHost, for instance, you should check `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, `/var/log/apache2/your-vhost_error.log`, and `/var/log/user.log`.

Comment: the web server is Apache. i opened  Error log in CPanel and it was empty. is it correct?

Comment: If you don't know debugging basics please, go find some material on it first. The only way to get help is with debugging output 90% of the time. Have you checked the browser for console errors? Perhaps you have an AJAX upload library at play like Dropzone.js. What have YOU done for the website to break? It is usually something you are forgetting. The slightest thing. Did you composer update? WHAT DID YOU DOOO??

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade laravel file manager. So follow below steps to make it working:

```
composer update unisharp/laravel-filemanager
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_view --force
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public --force
 php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config --force
```

Clear browser cache if page is broken after upgrading.

Comment: Why do you believe this will solve the 500 error when it was previously working OK?